# NoClassDefFoundError in AlertDialog.Builder

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, android-4.2-jelly-bean

I want to show `AlertDialog.Builder` for checking internet its working fine in android 5 and above but below version its showing exception like this

```
02-01 12:11:49.805 3220-3220/com.iglulabs.medine1 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.iglulabs.medine1, PID: 3220
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.iglulabs.medine1.utils.Utility$6
    at com.iglulabs.medine1.utils.Utility.showExistingEmailUserLoginDialog(Utility.java:1116)
    at com.iglulabs.medine1.activity.LoginActivity.onClick(LoginActivity.java:661)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4446)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18437)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5447)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:970)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:786)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

i tried a lot but i am not able to find the solution please help me to solve this problem.

my code is

```
AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(LoginActivity.this, R.style.MyAlertDialogStyle);
    dialogBuilder.setTitle(title);
    dialogBuilder.setMessage(message);
    dialogBuilder.setCancelable(false);
    dialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("Proceed", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.dismiss();
            ((AlertResult.RedeemPointResult) processResult).alertResult(true);
        }
    });

    dialogBuilder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.dismiss();
            ((AlertResult.RedeemPointResult) processResult).alertResult(false);
        }
    });

    dialogBuilder.show();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Multidex` ref this link
[Multidex](http://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html)